# How to keep sidebar from moving to the middle?

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar that has a list of the products categories and in the main body I have created a repeat region to show those products based on the category clicked. If I choose an empty category the design stays the same but when I choose a category that has products in it somehow the sidebar comes to the middle of the page and even the footer becomes smaller.

I didn't have problem with the sidebar before I created the repeat region and it didn't move or anything. I have created a fiddle that has the page & css file. Please let me know if I missed anything as I haven't used fiddle before. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/w4rhvbL0/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IndexStyle.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="body">
    <header class="MainHeader">
    <img src="images/header-image-5.jpg">
    <nav><ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="Product.php">Products</a></li>
         <li><a href="AboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="ContactUs.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="MainBody">
    <h1>Products
      </h1>
      <div class="productsresult">
<?php if ($totalRows_ProductsData > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty ?>
<?php do { ?>
    <div class="products"> <p><?php echo $row_ProductsData['product_name']; ?>
        <?php echo $row_ProductsData['price']; ?>
        <?php echo $row_ProductsData['image']; ?></p>
        <?php } while ($row_ProductsData = mysql_fetch_assoc($ProductsData)); ?>
    </div>
<?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
<?php if ($totalRows_ProductsData == 0) { // Show if recordset empty ?>
  There are no products in this category!
  <?php } // Show if recordset empty ?>
     </div>
     </div>
    <aside class="SideBar">
<?php include ("/includes/catalogue.php"); ?>
    </aside>
    <Footer class="Footer"> 
        <p>Copyrights reserved 
        </p>

    </Footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if you put the sidebar aside tag under the header tag above the "MainBody" class

Comment: @blecaf It makes the page layout worse.

Comment: Is the jsfiddle not working as shown in the pictures for anybody else? I'm having trouble seeing the issue described.

Comment: Post your rendered HTML -- the PHP is irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you check this condition `if ($totalRows_ProductsData > 0) {`

But you don't close your tags correctly. This is the HTML your code generates:

```
<div class="productsresult">
    <div class="products"><p>.....</p>
        <div class="products"><p>.....</p>
            <div class="products"><p>.....</p>
</div>
<aside class="SideBar"></aside>
```

Note that you don't close your `div` inside the `while` loop, so it generate an invalid HTML structure, and put the `aside` element inside the unclosed `div` tags resulted by the loop.

The browser "fix" this unclosed tags by auto-closing them, so you can end up with the following structure:

```
<div class="productsresult">
    <div class="products"><p>.....</p>
        <div class="products"><p>.....</p>
            <div class="products"><p>.....</p></div>
            <aside class="SideBar"></aside>
            <Footer class="Footer">....</Footer>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

To fix this you need to change the following:

```
<div class="productsresult">
<?php if ($totalRows_ProductsData > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty ?>
    <?php do { ?>
        <div class="products"> 
            <p>
                <?php echo $row_ProductsData['product_name']; ?>
                <?php echo $row_ProductsData['price']; ?>
                <?php echo $row_ProductsData['image']; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php } while ($row_ProductsData = mysql_fetch_assoc($ProductsData)); ?>
<?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
<?php if ($totalRows_ProductsData == 0) { // Show if recordset empty ?>
    There are no products in this category!
<?php } // Show if recordset empty ?>
</div>

<aside class="SideBar">
    <?php include ("/includes/catalogue.php"); ?>
</aside>
```

The above code will result the following code:

```
<div class="productsresult">
    <div class="products"><p>.....</p></div>
    <div class="products"><p>.....</p></div>
    <div class="products"><p>.....</p></div>
</div>
<aside class="SideBar"></aside>
```

Note that if you need only **one** products wrapper div, you should change the code to this:

```
<div class="productsresult">
<?php if ($totalRows_ProductsData > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty ?>
    <div class="products"> 
        <?php do { ?>
            <p>
                <?php echo $row_ProductsData['product_name']; ?>
                <?php echo $row_ProductsData['price']; ?>
                <?php echo $row_ProductsData['image']; ?>
            </p>
        <?php } while ($row_ProductsData = mysql_fetch_assoc($ProductsData)); ?>
    </div>
<?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
<?php if ($totalRows_ProductsData == 0) { // Show if recordset empty ?>
    There are no products in this category!
<?php } // Show if recordset empty ?>
</div>
```

Which will result the following structure:

```
<div class="productsresult">
    <div class="products">
        <p>.....</p>
        <p>.....</p>
        <p>.....</p>
    </div>
</div>
<aside class="SideBar"></aside>
```

Comment: I can't show how grateful I'm!  thank you, it works perfectly.